# Compare the input field value with the database field value in reactjs in a login form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement

I want to compare the input field value with the database field value in reactjs in a login form and put an alert if the both values are correct or not like the alert('Username or Password does not match!') will pop if the password entered is wrong or the username.

login.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Button, Form } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router'

export default function Login() {
    let navigate = useNavigate()

    const[username, setusername] = useState('');
    const[Employee_password, setEmployee_password] = useState('');
    
    const GetData = (e) =>{
         e.preventDefault();
        console.log(username, Employee_password)


    if(username !== employee.username && Employee_password !== Employee_password)
    {
        alert('Username or Password does not match!')
        return false
    }

    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/emp/login',{
        username,
        Employee_password
    })
    console.log('username', username)
    
    .then((res)=>{
        console.log('Login Successfull')
        navigate('/read')
    }).catch(err=>{
        console.log(err)
    })
    }
return(
    <div>
        <Form onClick={GetData} className='create-form'>
        <h2>Login into existing ID</h2>
        <Form.Field>
            <label>Enter Username</label>
            <input type='text' placeholder='Username' onChange={(e) => setusername(e.target.value)}></input>
        </Form.Field>
        <Form.Field>
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type='password' placeholder='Password' onChange={(e) => setEmployee_password(e.target.value)}></input>
        </Form.Field>
        <Button type='submit'>Login</Button>
        </Form>
    </div>
 )
```

}

Comment: Is your database password hashed ?

Comment: nope it is not hashed.